# IPTables - Redirect traffic based on country

Tags: iptables, port, tcp, whitelist

Is there any way how to allow TCP traffic only from specified countries on a specified port and the rest of traffic redirect to another IP/port using iptables ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set up and update the geoip database before it works.

```
iptables -I INPUT -m geoip -p tcp --dport ### --src-cc CN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -m geoip -p tcp --dport ###  --src-cc ! CN -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:333
```

replace 1.1.1.1 with your IP and 333 with whatever port you want.

Here is a tutorial to help you out:
http://xmodulo.com/block-network-traffic-by-country-linux.html
Apparently this link has died so I am adding one for internet archive.

https://web.archive.org/web/20190410142529/http://xmodulo.com/block-network-traffic-by-country-linux.html

You will need to periodically update the databases as sometimes ip addresses change owners and countries.

Comment: But wouldn't this cause a tremendous slowdown? It would be called for every packet, after all.

Comment: @DanielB If your rules are done correctly and in the correct order the performance impact will be minimal.  However, the user wants to do it, and they will have to decide if the CPU utilization is worth it.  I have a redirect for my web server and the impact is negligible.  Your supposed to have this rule at the top of the INPUT chain: **iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j ACCEPT --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED This passes all except new and bogus packets.**

Comment: It does not seem to work: iptables v1.4.14: unknown option "--dport"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Comment: try adding  **-m tcp -p tcp**

Comment: If you need to do multiple ports add **-m multiport** and change **--dport** to **--dports**

Comment: I don't need to add multiple ports but thy syntax does not simply work.

Comment: .After running first command it says "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name"

Comment: When run second command it says "iptables v1.6.1: unknown option "--src-cc"

Comment: @Infinity  I added "-m geoip to the second command, try that.  As far as the 1st command, Did you copy and paste?  If not the -j is lower case and the ACCEPT has to be upper case or it definitely won't work.  Also INPUT has to be upper case.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m geoip -p tcp --dport xxx --src-cc CN -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport xxx --src-cc ! CZ,SK -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:333
```

But your answer was correct.

Comment: so close, I guess the **-m tcp** must be one of the conditions for multi-port.  I updated my answer to reflect that change.

Comment: Ok, I have marked your response as correct then